# Google Cloud Pub/Sub Node.js Sample: TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-compute-engine, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-platform

I'm using GCP and I want to use Cloud Pub/Sub. I got this error below when I tried Node.js sample. Does anyone knows how to fix it?

```
/private/tmp/pubsub/pubsubsample.js:26
  subscription.on('error', onError);
              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null
    at /private/tmp/pubsub/pubsubsample.js:26:15
    at /private/tmp/pubsub/node_modules/gcloud/lib/pubsub/index.js:474:7
    at Object.handleResp (/private/tmp/pubsub/node_modules/gcloud/lib/common/util.js:113:3)
    at /private/tmp/pubsub/node_modules/gcloud/lib/common/util.js:422:12
    at Request.onResponse [as _callback] (/private/tmp/pubsub/node_modules/gcloud/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:106:7)
    at Request.self.callback (/private/tmp/pubsub/node_modules/gcloud/node_modules/request/request.js:198:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/private/tmp/pubsub/node_modules/gcloud/node_modules/request/request.js:1035:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
```

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node

```
var gcloud = require('gcloud');

// Authenticating on a per-API-basis. You don't need to do this if you
// auth on a global basis (see Authentication section above).

var pubsub = gcloud.pubsub({
  projectId: 'xxxxx',
  keyFilename: 'xxx.json'
});

// Reference a topic that has been previously created.
var topic = pubsub.topic('info');

// Publish a message to the topic.
topic.publish({
  data: 'New message!'
}, function(err) {});

// Subscribe to the topic.
topic.subscribe('new-subscription', function(err, subscription) {
  // Register listeners to start pulling for messages.
  function onError(err) {}
  function onMessage(message) {}
  subscription.on('error', onError);
  subscription.on('message', onMessage);

  // Remove listeners to stop pulling for messages.
  subscription.removeListener('message', onMessage);
  subscription.removeListener('error', onError);
});
```

... I'm using now PubSub but I'm thinking whether I can do same thing by using Google Cloud PubSub.

This post may be relevant. [Node.js on Google Cloud Platform Pub/Sub tutorial worker is failing with "TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677889/node-js-on-google-cloud-platform-pub-sub-tutorial-worker-is-failing-with-typeer)

---

Update 1

I changed to this code but same error was showed.

(error)

```
subscription.on('error', onError);
            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null
```

(code)

```
// Subscribe to the topic
topic.subscribe('new-subscription', function(err, subscription) {
  if( err ) {
    // something went wrong, react!
    return;
  }

  // Register listeners to start pulling for messages.
  function onError(err) {}
  function onMessage(message) {}
  subscription.on('error', onError);
  subscription.on('message', onMessage);

  // Remove listeners to stop pulling for messages.
  subscription.removeListener('message', onMessage);
  subscription.removeListener('error', onError);
});
```

---

Update 2

My expectation is this below.

1. execute "node pubsub.js"
2. I can see the sample message 'New message!'

Comment: the `subscribe()` callback does currently not check for the `err` parameter, before using `subscription`. I bet, the `err` shows you, what's wrong.

Comment: @Sirko Thanks your response. I'm still not sure what should I do next... Can you give me more advices..

Comment: I'm sorry I removed the tag.

Comment: Cool thanks. Just wanted to make sure you didn't need our assistance with anything. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When invoking `topic.subscribe()`, the method essentially invokes the `pubsub.subscribe()` method with a specific Topic instance as its context. This can be seen from the [source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node/blob/v0.27.0/lib/pubsub/topic.js) under `Topic.prototype.subscribe`.

Based on the PubSub [index.js source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node/blob/v0.27.0/lib/pubsub/index.js), `PubSub.prototype.subscribe()` issues a HTTP request to create a new subscription respecting the [`projects.subscriptions.create` API](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/create) format. If the response returns a [`409 ALREADY_EXISTS`](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/error-codes) error and you have not set the `options.reuseExisting` to `true`, the callback you provided will be invoked with the error and `null` as a subscription. According to the PubSub Nodejs documentation for [`topic.subscribe`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.27.0/pubsub/topic?method=subscribe) under `options.reuseExisting`, the default value if not specified is `false` and

> If false, attempting to create a subscription that already exists will
>   fail.

To use this design more effectively, I would suggest the following:

```
var pubsub = require('gcloud').pubsub({
    "projectId" : "project-id",
    "keyFilename" : "key-file.json"
});

// This topic should already have been created
var topic = pubsub.topic("interesting-topic");

// The message that will be published
var message = {"data": "Welcome to this interesting thread"};

// Callback to throw an exception if publish was unsuccessful
// Will log published message IDs if successful
function publishedHandler(err, messageIds, responseBody) {
    if (err) {
        // Could not publish message(s)
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(messagesIds);
}

// Callback to throw an exception if a subscription could not be found or created
// Will attach event listeners if successfully gets a subscription
function subscriptionHandler(err, subscription, responseBody) {
    if (err) {
        // Could not get or create a new subscription
        throw err;
    }
    subscription.on("error", errorHandler);
    subscription.on("message", messageHandler);
}

// Publish a message to the topic
topic.publish(message, publishedHandler);

// Create or get 'sub' and subcribe it to 'interesting-topic'
topic.subscribe("sub", {"reuseExisting": true}, subscriptionHandler);
```

[Issue 696](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node/issues/696) may not refer exactly to this issue but does discuss some of the semantic choices made in designing the Node.js library for Cloud PubSub. It's not entirely clear if methods like `topic.publish` or `topic.subscribe` check for existence of a topic, existence of a subscription, create a new subscription or get an existing subscription. I would simply warn to add robust error handling.

Comment: Thank you. I've done what I wanted to do. I posted the result to my blog. http://www.yzono.com/entry/2016/01/30/054216 (Japanese)

Answer (score 3):

Currently you do not check for errors, when subscribing, but just errors while being subscribed. To change that, you can use something like this:

```
// Subscribe to the topic.
topic.subscribe('new-subscription', function(err, subscription) {

  // first check for errors
  if( err ) {
    // something went wrong, react!
    return;
  }

  // rest of your code

});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but same error was showed. I think subscription is null is something wrong.

Comment: @zono So `err` was null as well ?

Comment: No error if I set "Not Exist subscription key". Error shows if I set "exist subscription key". When I debug gcloud JS, the error shows "You set exist resource.." I thinks subscribe is OK. Then I opened another terminal and doing publishing to the same topic. But nothing happen... I may have to know data pulling or change to push type (set a specific URL to webhook...)

Comment: The accepted answer is right - but for those that just start with PubSub: Also check the `err` parameter right away - I.e. if you have not activated the API permission it will be set (while never triggering `onError`)